# What is the difference between Image Attribute and ImageURL in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have googled and crawled SO about this but couldn't find any reliable info.

What is the any difference between changing the photo source of an image in ASP.NET by

```
myImage.Attributes["src"] = "/files/image1.jpg";
```

and

```
myImage.ImageUrl = "~/files/image1.jpg";
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ImageUrl attribute has the advantage that you can use the ~ character, which stands for the application root.

```
myImage.ImageUrl = "~/files/image1.jpg";
```

This is useful in cases where the root of the application is in a subfolder and you don't need to hard code the folder's name in your code.